# How expensive is GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_DATA_DOWNSTREAM in GStreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I was looking over some probe types and was wondering how expensive probes such as `GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_DATA_DOWNSTREAM` are. How costly is it to attach logic to them as they're processing every buffer that passes through.

The context is that i'm looking at a performance bug and I'm wondering if even simple logic within `DATA_DOWNSTREAM` probe callbacks could lead to degradation.